# Hazelcast deserialize in another class

Tags: hazelcast

Hello I have a following questions. We are using Hazelcast IdentifiedSeializeable. Is it possible to deserialize an object that was serialized as one class for example User and deserialize it as another class AdminUser based on  presumption that the two classes have the same fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your factory accordingly and you read elements / fields in the same order they were written - yeah kind of. You only need to be aware that there is one more "small" issue as configurations need to be mostly similar or new nodes cannot join. So you most probably have to add some magic to your factory.

On the other hand why do you want to do this? Isn't it easier to wrap your user entity into a AdminUser instance after deserialization when you figured out it's an AdminUser?

Comment: It might be stupid, but I am kind of thinking in the sense of Microservices where one domain object may exist in several contexts containing different business logic. Basically I am thinking in a situation where someone is implementing a service holding its domain model that might be a different dimension in terms of logic to the same thing.

Comment: I guess the serializationID is written into the byte array together with the factoryID. I really have no clue what this magic might be :)

Comment: Not sure, never tried to do smt like that. If you microservices are clients there's no issue, just deserialize into a different object (as long as you keep the properties order), if you use embedded nodes this could be more complicated and you might want to use StreamSerializer instead storing additional data or logic.

Comment: Yes that is the correct pressumption "If they are clients" the things is that we have a lot of distributed functions. So I am kind of thinking in the context of these distributed functions if this is possible. The end goal is to avoid having a Unified Domain Model

Comment: Unfortunately my CBOR (cbor.io) codec and Hazelcast integration is not yet ready (at least not production ready), that could make your use case easier (at least for data / not functions).

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it.